# Running model prompt on stable diffusion model from hugging face on mps MacOS

Tags: python, torch, huggingface, mps

```
import gradio as gr
import torch
import numpy as np
import modin.pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
from diffusers import DiffusionPipeline
import os

os.environ["PYTORCH_MPS_HIGH_WATERMARK_RATIO"] = "0.0"

device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'mps'

if torch.cuda.is_available():
    PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF = {'max_split_size_mb': 8000}
    torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated(device=device)
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()

    pipe = DiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained("stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0", torch_dtype=torch.float16,
                                             variant="fp16", use_safetensors=True)
    pipe.enable_xformers_memory_efficient_attention()
    pipe = pipe.to(device)
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()

    refiner = DiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained("stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-refiner-1.0", use_safetensors=True,
                                                torch_dtype=torch.float16, variant="fp16")
    refiner.enable_xformers_memory_efficient_attention()
    refiner = refiner.to(device)
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()

    upscaler = DiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained("stabilityai/sd-x2-latent-upscaler", torch_dtype=torch.float16,
                                                 use_safetensors=True)
    upscaler.enable_xformers_memory_efficient_attention()
    upscaler = upscaler.to(device)
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
else:
    pipe = DiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained("stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0", use_safetensors=True)
    pipe = pipe.to(device)
    pipe.unet = torch.compile(pipe.unet, mode="reduce-overhead", fullgraph=True)
    refiner = DiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained("stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-refiner-1.0", use_safetensors=True)
    refiner = refiner.to(device)
    refiner.unet = torch.compile(refiner.unet, mode="reduce-overhead", fullgraph=True)

n_steps = 40
high_noise_frac = 0.8

pipe.enable_attention_slicing()
PYTORCH_MPS_HIGH_WATERMARK_RATIO=0.0

def genie(prompt, negative_prompt, height, width, scale, steps, seed, upscaling, prompt_2, negative_prompt_2):
    generator = torch.Generator(device=device).manual_seed(seed)
    int_image = pipe(prompt, prompt_2=prompt_2, negative_prompt=negative_prompt, negative_prompt_2=negative_prompt_2,
                     num_inference_steps=steps, height=height, width=width, guidance_scale=scale,
                     num_images_per_prompt=1, generator=generator, output_type="latent").images
    if upscaling == 'Yes':
        image = \
            refiner(prompt=prompt, prompt_2=prompt_2, negative_prompt=negative_prompt,
                    negative_prompt_2=negative_prompt_2,
                    image=int_image).images[0]
        upscaled = upscaler(prompt=prompt, negative_prompt=negative_prompt, image=image, num_inference_steps=5,
                            guidance_scale=0).images[0]
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()
        return (image, upscaled)
    else:
        image = \
            refiner(prompt=prompt, prompt_2=prompt_2, negative_prompt=negative_prompt,
                    negative_prompt_2=negative_prompt_2,
                    image=int_image).images[0]
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    return (image, image)


gr.Interface(fn=genie, inputs=[gr.Textbox(
    label='What you want the AI to generate. 77 Token Limit. A Token is Any Word, Number, Symbol, or Punctuation. Everything Over 77 Will Be Truncated!'),
    gr.Textbox(label='What you Do Not want the AI to generate. 77 Token Limit'),
    gr.Slider(512, 1024, 768, step=128, label='Height'),
    gr.Slider(512, 1024, 768, step=128, label='Width'),
    gr.Slider(1, 15, 10, step=.25,
              label='Guidance Scale: How Closely the AI follows the Prompt'),
    gr.Slider(25, maximum=100, value=50, step=25, label='Number of Iterations'),
    gr.Slider(minimum=1, step=1, maximum=999999999999999999, randomize=True, label='Seed'),
    gr.Radio(['Yes', 'No'], value='No', label='Upscale?'),
    gr.Textbox(label='Embedded Prompt'),
    gr.Textbox(label='Embedded Negative Prompt')],
             outputs=['image', 'image'],
             title="Stable Diffusion XL 1.0 GPU",
             description="SDXL 1.0 GPU. <br><br><b>WARNING: Capable of producing NSFW (Softcore) images.</b>",
             article="If You Enjoyed this Demo and would like to Donate, you can send to any of these Wallets. <br>BTC: bc1qzdm9j73mj8ucwwtsjx4x4ylyfvr6kp7svzjn84 <br>3LWRoKYx6bCLnUrKEdnPo3FCSPQUSFDjFP <br>DOGE: DK6LRc4gfefdCTRk9xPD239N31jh9GjKez <br>SHIB (BEP20): 0xbE8f2f3B71DFEB84E5F7E3aae1909d60658aB891 <br>PayPal: https://www.paypal.me/ManjushriBodhisattva <br>ETH: 0xbE8f2f3B71DFEB84E5F7E3aae1909d60658aB891 <br>Code Monkey: <a href=\"https://huggingface.co/Manjushri\">Manjushri</a>").launch(
    debug=True, max_threads=80)
```

This is an example of one usage, but all models that are related to graphics from `huggingface` returns the same error which is

Error

```
step_index = (self.timesteps == timestep).nonzero().item()

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

RuntimeError: Expected dst.dim() >= src.dim() to be true, but got false. (Could this error message be improved? If so, please report an enhancement request to PyTorch.)
```

Any suggestion please?

Thanks in advance

I was trying to generate image from prompt, and expected a PIL Image

Comment: `dst.dim() >= src.dim()`, does it work without upscaling?

Comment: @doneforaiur nope! 
Even with single pipe directly to the model, neither upscale nor refiner, always return the same error

Comment: *all models that are related to graphics from huggingface returns the same error*, what's the version of `huggingface`? Also, does it work without `mps`?